# Swift: how to set up an audio session that gracefully mixes with others (aka Pod)

Tags: audio, swift, ios8.1

This code snippet makes the other audio (aka iPod) to stop:

```
func setSessionPlayer() {

    var audioSessionError: NSError?
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    audioSession.setActive(true, error: nil)

    if audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers,
        error: &audioSessionError) {
            println("Successfully set the audio session")
    } else {
        println("Could not set the audio session")
    }

}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because you're setting the `audioSession.active` before it's configured to `MixWithOthers`.  Move `audioSession.setActive` below the if block like so:

```
if audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers,
    error: &audioSessionError) {
        println("Successfully set the audio session")
} else {
    println("Could not set the audio session")
}

audioSession.setActive(true, error: nil)
```