# Handling interruptions during a phone call - the "begin" works but the "end" doesn't

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession, interruptions

The app records audio and should stop recording audio when there is an interruption, such as a phone call, and then resume recording audio when the phone call ends.

The app currently registers when there is a phone call, but when I hang up the phone, the app does not register that the interruption has ended. (I have no other apps open).

### With function delegates

See code below in my ViewController.

```
func audioRecorderBeginInterruption(recorder: AVAudioRecorder){
    print("* * * * * * * inside begin interruption")}

func audioRecorderEndInterruption(recorder: AVAudioRecorder, withFlags flags: Int) {
    // THIS NEVER PRINTS, EVEN WHEN PHONE IS HUNG UP
    print("* * * * * * * inside end interruption")
}
```

### With notifications

I've also tried to handle interruptions with notifications, but the .Ended is still not handled, unless I receive a phone call and I decline the call. See code in my AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

        center.addObserver(self,
            selector:"sessionInterrupted:",
            name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification,
            object:AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()) //self.myViewController.audioSession)


        return true
    }



 func sessionInterrupted(notification: NSNotification){
                if let typeValue = notification.userInfo?[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? NSNumber{
                    if let type = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue.unsignedLongValue){
                        if type == .Began{
                            print("interruption: began")
                        } else{
                            // THIS ALSO NEVER PRINTS
                            print("interruption: ended")
                        }
        }
```

## Related Solutions that did not work for me

1. Solution: Adding `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];` which did not work

   - [AVAudioRecorder not recording in background after audio session interruption ended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036294/avaudiorecorder-not-recording-in-background-after-audio-session-interruption-end?rq=1)
   - [iOS Audio session hands on](http://ritzinmobileworld.blogspot.com/2014/05/ios-audio-session-hands-on.html)
2. Solution: Use `MixWithOthers`, which may work for resuming playing audio, but does not work in my case for resuming recording audio

   - [Swift: how to set up an audio session that gracefully mixes with others (aka Pod)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655402/swift-how-to-set-up-an-audio-session-that-gracefully-mixes-with-others-aka-pod)
   - [AVAudioPlayer play not working after incoming FaceTime interruption](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15514)

## Current Hypothesis

My current hypothesis is that the "Ended" interruption is only for interruptions such as when you get a phone call, and you decline the call, but not for if you actually pick up the phone, talk for a bit, and then hang up. My guess is there is no way to detect the latter case, without using a jailbroken phone.

Expanded on in a broader way here: [iOS AVAudioSession interruption notification not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806155/ios-avaudiosession-interruption-notification-not-working-as-expected?rq=1)

This hypothesis appears to be verified in [DropVox's FAQ](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/help/dropvox/):

> Only one app has control over audio at a time. If DropVox is recording
>   and another app takes control, that’s called an “interruption.” When
>   the interruption is over, it’s only possible for DropVox to resume
>   recording if its in the foreground[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371388/detecting-active-avaudiosessions-on-ios-device), which is why we caution against
>   using the “Record in the background” setting.

I could possibly handle the interruptions by using [routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371388/detecting-active-avaudiosessions-on-ios-device) to detect the microphone is being used. But I don't think that I can re-activate audio recording in the background, so I would do that once the app is back in the foreground.

Is that right?

Comment: Did you found any solutions?

Comment: Apple docs do have a line in them (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH4-SW5) saying:  "There is no guarantee that a begin interruption will have an end interruption. Your app needs to be aware of switching to a foreground running state or the user pressing a play button. In either case, determine whether your app should reactivate its audio session."

Answer (score -2):

**DO NOT** active audiosession in `applicationWillResignActive:/applicationDidBecomeActive:` function !

when the phone call reached, the system own the audiosession,at this time if you call function `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error]` in the `applicationWillResignActive:/applicationDidBecomeActive:` function ,your app will own the audiosession back(actually it should be fail to active audiosession when the phone call,but I don't know why it return true) and will not receive the end interruption.